# How to add my own css in ASP.Net Core 5.0 Project

Tags: css, asp.net-core

I am trying to add my own css in ASP.Net Core project but without success. In the StartUp.cs file everything is set up correct. I am using StaticFiles and RazorPages. When change the css and when click inspect on the browser I see that the changes are changed but it is not loaded on the site. Please help.

Comment: can you provide more information?

Comment: I try to change the site.css but nothing is changed. Also I tried to create new CSS file in wwwroot/css but again nothing

Answer (score 0):

You should put your own `.css` file in `css` folder. I have test it, and it works for me.

**Default style:**

[image]

**Use my own css:**

[image]

[image]